# How to keep a login session from a cross origin (CORS) Spring security without sending another authentication request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cross-domain

I have a Spring boot app server protected by spring security. The user is authenticated with a username and password when they first log in. If I use Spring MVC (same origin) I didn't have to re-login every time I call an API. But when I call the API from an Angular app (cross-origin), I have to provide an authorization every time I refresh the page.

Is it possible to keep my login session without having to send an auth every time I refresh the page? Do I need some kind of HTTP interceptor service to check the response from the Spring server manually?

**The REST API I tried to call**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class TestControllers {
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public MessageModel greeting (@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new MessageModel(counter.incrementAndGet(),"Hello, " + name + "!");
    }

    private class MessageModel{
        private long id;
        private String content;
        //Constructor, getter & setter
    }
}
```

**Auth controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class BasicAuthController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/basicauth")
    public AuthenticationModel basicauth() {
        return new AuthenticationModel("You are authenticated");
    }

    class AuthenticationModel {
        private String message;
        //Constructor, getter & setter
    }
}
```

**The security configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(encoder)
                .withUser("user")
                .password(encoder.encode("asdasd"))
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

**The Angular authentication service**

```
authenticationService(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/basicauth',
      { headers: { authorization: this.createBasicAuthToken(username, password) } }).pipe(map((res) => {
      this.username = username;
      this.password = password;
      this.registerSuccessfulLogin(username, password);
    }));
  }
```

Comment: In your case there are several options to securize your requests after the login one. One of the most widely used is JWT token, in that way, after login, back will return a new token that you will use in front/back to securite your "other requests"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an interceptor for your Angular client, so make a new injectable like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const username = this.authenticationService.username; //get your credentials from wherever you saved them after authentification
    const password = this.authenticationService.password;
    if (username && password) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: this.createBasicAuthToken(username, password),
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

and add this to your `providers` located in `app.module.ts`:

```
{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true},
```

This will add your authentication data to each request so you don't have to login every time.

Comment: The approach is correct but not the information you will need to store for that: `username` and `password`. Store them in front to use them in an interceptor is not secure

Comment: @doctore What is the correct way to secure the information then?

Comment: There are several links that explain how work with JWT + Spring + Angular. Basically, the idea is use the `login` endpoint only once (with `user/password`), that one will return a token to your Angular application. At this point, you can save it using, for example, local storage, using an Angular Http interceptor to send it in every subsequent request to backend. Now in your Spring security code, you will be able to use the provided JWT token to allow (or not) the incoming request.